# C# Entity Framework Core .NET5.0 unit test pending migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have just migrated microservice from Core 3.1 to .net5.0 and I cannot seem to figure out a way to migrate my unit test checks if there is forgotten pending migration.

My code that worked on Core 3.1

```
    [Fact]
    public void WhenHavePendingMigrations_ThenTestFails()
    {
        const string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=0;User Id=a;Password=a;";
        var db = DesignTimeContext.CreateDbContext(connectionString);

        var migrationsAssembly = db.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>();
        var differ = db.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>();

        var hasDifferences = differ.HasDifferences(
            migrationsAssembly.ModelSnapshot.Model,
            db.Model);

        Assert.False(hasDifferences, "You forgot to add a migration!");
    }
```

Could someone please help to migrate this code to .net5 with the exact same logic, providing code sample for checking for pending migrations in .net5?

Comment: What is not working about your way to migrate it? What problems do you face, what errors do you get? Where are you stuck?

Comment: differ.HasDifferences method now recieves IRelationalModel interface, but Model property now is of IModel interface, so I cannot even call that method.with this example. I tried converting  using GetRelationalModel extension method, but that threw InvalidOperationException with message "The model needs to be finalized before the database model can be accessed.".

Comment: I always check ef source code (the unit tests) when I get stuck on these things. Maybe this one will help you: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/bca8fa5c79b2f75c94cbd3dc1984398a5aa13a36/test/EFCore.Relational.Specification.Tests/Migrations/MigrationsInfrastructureTestBase.cs#L307